# Why does Swagger-UI show unnecessary fields for MultiNotificationRequest?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

Sprinfox-boot-starter problem with inherited classes.

I have three classes NotificationRequest,SingleNotificationRequest,MultinotificationRequest. SingleNotificationRequest and MultiNotificationRequest classes extend NotificationRequest.

My problem is swagger shows unnecessary fields for multinotificationRequest. see the picture below.

[image]
I only need content,file,title and array of ids for multiNotification request controller. See the controller class below

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(API_VERSION + "/notification")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NotificationController {
    private final NotificationService notificationService;



    @PostMapping(value = "/sendMultipleByWeb", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendNotificationByWeb(@Valid @ModelAttribute MultiNotificationRequest notificationRequest, BindingResult result) throws MethodArgumentNotValidException {
        return notificationService.sendMultipleNotificationByWeb(notificationRequest, result);
    }
}
```

This is notificationRequest,singleNotificationRequest and mutlfiNotificationRequest classes :

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@SuperBuilder
public class NotificationRequest {
    @JsonProperty("title")
    @NotBlank(message = "notification.title.not.valid")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("content")
    @NotBlank(message = "notification.content.not.valid")
    private String content;

    @JsonProperty("photo")
    private MultipartFile photo;


}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@SuperBuilder
public class SingleNotificationRequest extends NotificationRequest {
    @JsonProperty("userId")
    @NotNull(message = "notification.userId.not.null")
    private Long userId;


}


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@SuperBuilder
public class MultiNotificationRequest extends NotificationRequest {

    private List<Long> userIds;

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<SingleNotificationRequest> getSingleNotifications() {
        return userIds.stream()
                .map(id -> (SingleNotificationRequest) SingleNotificationRequest.builder()
                        .title(getTitle())
                        .userId(id)
                        .content(getContent())
                        .photo(getPhoto())
                        .build()
                ).toList();

    }

}
```

How can I fix this ?

I have not tried anything yet but I want swagger-ui to show only required fields.
swagger-ui is working fine with single notificationRequest but MultinotificationRequest with array of userIds showing problems

Comment: I don't know why but after removing getSingleNotifications() method from MultiNotificationRequest class everything came back to normal